# Adding two lists by addition based on keys

Tags: python

I was thinking of performing addition in lists.

```
listA = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
listB = [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

using `zip` I get

```
listC = [['a', 1], ['b', 3], ['a', 5], ['b', 7]]
```

My goal is to get

```
listC = [['a', 6], ['b', 10]]
```

I remember `Scala` has a nice map function. But I tried applying the same to python, but I am unable to get any idea on modification.

Comment: I edited your question because convention in Python is to start variables' names with lower case letters ; uppercase is for class names

Comment: @ted - convention in python is to use snake_case

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `defaultdict` from `collections` like,

```
>>> ListA
['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
>>> ListB
[1, 3, 5, 7]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for key,val in zip(ListA, ListB):
...   d[key] += val
... 
>>> list(d.items())
[('a', 6), ('b', 10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for a, b in zip(ListA, ListB):
    d[a] += b

list(d.items())
# [('a', 6), ('b', 10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build dictionary while reading the two lists:

```
listA = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
listB = [1, 3, 5, 7]

result = {}
for A, B in zip(listA, listB):
    if A in result:
        result[A] += B
    else:
        result[A] = B
result = result.items()
print(result)
```

This should give you your result:
`dict_items([('a', 6), ('b', 10)])`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use a dictionary:

```
listA = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
listB = [1, 3, 5, 7]

result = {}
for k, v in zip(listA, listB):
    result[k] = result.get(k, 0) + v
result = [list(items) for items in result.items()]
# or
result = list(map(list, result.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: get a list of each unique key by turning `ListA` into a set.

```
Keys = set(ListA)
# ['a, 'b']
```

Then you can use list enumeration to sum up each occurance

```
List C = [sum([v for j, v in zip(ListA, ListB) if j == k]) for k in Keys]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that will do the job:

```
ListA = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
ListB = [1, 3, 5, 7]
output={}
for index,key in enumerate(ListA):
    if key in output:
        output[key]+=ListB[int(index)]
    else:
        output[key]=ListB[int(index)]
final_out = [[k, v] for k, v in output.items()]
print(final_out)
```

Output:

```
[['a', 6], ['b', 10]]
```